# Combine 3 functions into one program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a programming question that might sound very easy for most of you but I'm stuck and can't figure out how to solve it. Would be really helpful if someone could sort this out for me.

I'm making a program that is like a bank simulator and it consists of a class (Account) and a couple of methods and functions. The bank is supposed to be able to set up a new account, do withdrawal, change PIN-code and so on.

Not sure if any of this matters to the problem, but  anyways, what I want to do now is to run the program. I've got 3 functions that I want to include:

```
menu() # Just prints the menu. Like "Hi! What to you want to do? 1. Withdrawal 2. Change PIN" and so on...

menu_choice(): # An input. Choose a number between 1-6
    choice = input("Choose a number!")
    execute(choice)

execute(choice) # A code with six "if":s that does different stuff depending on the menu_choice().
```

The question is: How do I combine these three into one program?

I want the menu to print and the menu choice to go into execute. This is supposed to repeat until the menu_choice() is == 6, because that is the option "End program".

But how do I do it, is it like a while loop or something?

Comment: You should do a "while true: menu_choice()" and execute. Break the while only if 6 is reacjed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather restructure the code as below:

```
#Returns a number if input is valid and None otherwise
def get_choice():
    try:
        return int(input("choose a number! "))
    except ValueError:
        return None

def execute(choice):
    print("execute %i" % choice)

def main():
    while True:
        choice = get_choice()
        if choice is None: #make sure input is valid
            continue.      #ask again
        if choice != 6:
            execute(choice)
        else:
            break          #choice == 6

 main()
```

Main is implemented as a while loop. It checks for valid input before executing the target function. It asks the user again if input is invalid. It runs as long as the choice is not equal to 6.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do an infinite recursion of your commands, do:

```
while True: # while needs a condition that is True. True is obviously True. 1 < 2 would be True as well, 2 < 1 not.
    menu_choice()
```

Use `break` inside the loop if you want to break out from that loop.

If you want to run a command `n` times, than do:

```
for i in range(n):
    menu_choice()
```

where `i` holds the current cycle number.

Comment: Thanks! I use "while True" and I'm almost done, just can't figure out how to break it. I though of something like 
   if menu_choice() == 6: break, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Your idea is right. It should work as expected. However, `input()` results are always **strings** , which aren't equal to numbers (integers). So you would either do `if int(menu_choice()) == 6: break` which would convert the string to an integer and throw an error if it was a text or do `if menu_choice() == "6"` which makes "6" a string. I hope this is working for you. If it's working, you could accept (green check mark) and upvote my answer, if you want.

Comment: Unfortunately neither works. My menu_choice is programmed so that it always takes in an integer, and it doesn't accept strings. 
It still doesn't break the loop though.

I tried:


    ´while True:
    menu()
    menu_choice()
    if menu_choice() == 6:
        break´

Comment: Well, there must be some problem. In your code I see that you are calling menu_choice() twice. Did you fill in "6" twice too? Only the second time is in the if statement. The first choice is therefore being ignored. Do you **return** your choice inside `menu_choice` ?

Comment: I invited you to a chat room with me, Jonas. I will help could help you personally there.

Answer (score 0):

First, add one extra line in the menu_choice() function: ##***Edited***##

```
def menu():
    print("Hi! What to you want to do? 1. Withdrawal 2. Change PIN")

def execute(choice):
    if choice == 1:
        print("1") 
    elif choice == 2:
        print("2") 
    elif choice == 3:
        print("3") 
    elif choice == 4:
        print("4")
    elif choice == 5:
        print("5") 
    elif choice == 6:
        print("6") 
        return 1
    return 0

def menu_choice():
    menu()
    choice = int(input("Choose a number!"))
    should_the_loop_break = execute(choice)
    return should_the_loop_break
```

You can call the menu_choice() method in two ways:

1) Infinite loop: ##***Edited***##

```
while True:
    should_the_loop_break = menu_choice()
    if should_the_loop_break == 1:
        break
```

2) A given no. of times

```
for i in range(0,n):
    menu_choice()
```

Let me know if it works/gives an error!

PS: Please ignore the spelling mistakes with variable names.

Comment: Nice! I did the 1). Now it's infinite thought, so how do I know make the loop stop if choice ==6 ?
Is it like 
if choice == 6: False or something like that...?